# JS condition with map and reduce

Tags: javascript

```
{
change: "credit"
currency: "EUR"
value: "30.00"
}
{
change: "debit"
currency: "EUR"
value: "15.00"
}
```

This is working and returning the correct result:

```
const totalMovements = customerMovements.map(a => parseFloat(a.value).reduce((acc, n) => acc + n)
```

I want the sum of the values with `change === 'credit'`. The result should be 30. This is not working when i add the 'change' condition, can someone help?:

```
const totalMovements = customerMovements.map(a => parseFloat(a.value) && a.change === 'credit').reduce((acc, n) => acc + n)
```

Comment: You're returning a boolean in your `map` in the second example, so the array you end up reducing is just an array of booleans. `[true, false].reduce(...`. It looks like you want to filter by credit and then sum?

Comment: What isn't working? Please add the desired output

Comment: Are you sure the first example is working? `parseFloat(a.value).reduce((acc, n) => acc + n)`

Comment: I want the sum of the values with change = credit. The result should be 30.
The first example is returning 45, and its correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a boolean in your `map` in the second example, so the array you end up reducing is just an array of booleans. `[true, false].reduce(...`.

It looks like you want to [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) by credit and then sum?

```js
const customerMovements = [{ change: 'credit', currency: 'EUR', value: '30.00', }, { change: 'debit', currency: 'EUR', value: '15.00', },];

const totalMovements = customerMovements
    .map((a) => parseFloat(a.value))
    .reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0);

console.log(totalMovements);

const totalCredits = customerMovements
    .filter(({ change }) => change === 'credit')
    .map((a) => parseFloat(a.value))
    .reduce((acc, n) => acc + n, 0);

console.log(totalCredits);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the result using just [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), either way will work!

```js
const customerMovements = [ { change: "credit", currency: "EUR", value: "30.00" }, { change: "debit", currency: "EUR", value: "15.00" } ]
const totalMovements = customerMovements.reduce((acc, { value, change }) => { 
    return acc + (change === 'credit' ? parseFloat(value): 0)
}, 0)
console.log(totalMovements)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I confirm, it work too! tks

Comment: Just another way of doing it, :-). The accepted answer is very good and will work nicely of course!